# General mobility help for Strong Lifts?

Tags: stronglifts, mobility

I've seen a lot of remarks in different places about mobility work to help you to achieve the full range of motion in your lifts.  Are there general mobility workouts that one can do to help them with their lifts if you are doing the Strong Lifts program?

Answer (score 5):

In case you have not seen them, there are three sites on the StrongLifts page itself dedicated to increasing mobility.

- [Shoulder dislocations](http://stronglifts.com/shoulders-dislocations/)
- [Shoulder pec stretches](http://stronglifts.com/squats-improve-shoulder-flexibility-how-to/)
- [Thoracic Extension on roller](http://stronglifts.com/squats-improve-posture-flexibility-how-to/)

Of those I have only been doing the shoulder dislocations. Contrary to what the author of stronglifts says I would not recommend using a flexible band. This only makes it harder to keep your arms parallel to each other. Of course I didn't come up with that itself, it's what the coach in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoGtrEcsqPQ) says.

Answer (score 0):

I have found these exercises helpful for increasing mobility, see [MAQ complex](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JBlPQOUl1zw). 
Besides helping mobilty, they also work as warm-up exercise.